# Using command to open Privacy & Security > Proflies page

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, macos-ventura

I'd like to use the command to open the Profiles page under Privacy & Security panel.
[image]

Currently, I'm using the following command:

```
open /System/Library/PreferencePanes/Profiles.prefPane
```

This works on one of my devices with macOS version 13.6.3.

However, another device with version 13.1 only opens the Privacy & Security page instead of the Profiles page.
[image]

Is there any other command that would cover both operating system versions?